# I want to make my character jump in pygame and it's not working

Tags: python, pygame

I tried to make my character jump and it's not working. So when I press SPACE the y position should decrement to make my player go up and when he reaches the top I wanted to make it come down again.
I don't know what to say the site makes me describe the problem even more to post it so here am I am writing words :)

This is the code by now:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
#variabile
velPlayer = 1
xPlayer = 100
yPlayer = 100

#initializare
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,1000))
pygame.display.set_caption("Joculet")

#fundal
def ecranAlb():
    screen.fill((255,255,255))

#player   
def player():
    global xPlayer, yPlayer
    isJump = False
    jumpCount = 10
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,253),(xPlayer,yPlayer,15,15))
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and xPlayer < 971:
        xPlayer += velPlayer
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and xPlayer > 0:
        xPlayer -= velPlayer
    if not(isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and yPlayer > 0:
            yPlayer -= velPlayer
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and yPlayer < 970:
            yPlayer += velPlayer
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1

            yPlayer = (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10

#main loop   
running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    ecranAlb()
    player()
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Instead of writing words just for the sake of writing more words you could have written what the problem is with the code you have shown and what you want to ask about it.

Answer (score 1):

`isJump` and `jumpCount` must be initialized before the application loop in global namespce. Use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) to change the variable in global namespace within the function:

```py
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10

def player():
    global xPlayer, yPlayer, isJump, jumpCount 

    # [...]
```